# Training a model that converts plain text to JSON

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am new to this, so I can be formulating this question incorrectly

I want to use an existing model or train/fine-tune an existing one in order to convert semi-arbitrary text to a predictable JSON format

For example given such text

[image]

I'd like to turn it into JSON

```
{
  "days": [
    { title: "Day 1", activities: [{ name: "A day in Madrid", text: "Start your day.." }],
    { title: "Day 2", activities: [{ name: "A day in Barcelona", text: "Start your day.." }],
  ]
}
```

My question is what is this task called in huggingface models? I assume this is Text2Text generation

If so, what model should I use? Would appreciate some general guidelines

If I understand it correctly I will have to train it with a bunch of JSONL lines

Comment: [Flan-T5](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/flan-t5) or T5 in general.